# PostgreSQL slow count/group/date_trunc mix

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have the following query:

```
select count(*), date_trunc('day', updated_at) from test group by date_trunc('day', updated_at);
```

and the when explaining I have the following:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=213481.83..223749.85 rows=245009 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=213481.83..215883.63 rows=960720 width=8)
      Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, updated_at))
  ->  Index Only Scan using updatedat on test  (cost=0.00..91745.26 rows=960720 width=8)
```

As you can see it has a high cost, and the query time is 6231.58 ms.

Is there a way to improve this? What should be the best index to create for this kind of count/group/date_trunc mix.

Comment: 2 questions: What happens if you execute the query several times? Can you try with an index on `date_trunc('day', updated_at')` (postgresql allows to create index on expressions, not only on columns)? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers) ...` (not just a simple explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are really 250000 different days in your table, you probably cannot do much better than this. Increasing `work_mem` will speed up the sort though.

If, however, the number of different days is significantly lower, the problem is that PostgreSQL has no way to estimate the distribution of `date_trunc`'s results unless you create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test (date_trunc('day', updated_at));
```

If `updated_at` is a `timestamp without time zone`, that will work fine. For a `timestamp with time zone`, you'll have to specify a time zone, because otherwise the result will depend on the session time zone, which makes it unusable for an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test (date_trunc('day', updated_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```

Then `ANALYZE` the table, increase `work_mem` and see if you can get a hash aggregate instead of a sort.

Of course, if you have to use `AT TIME ZONE`in the index definition, you'd also have to use it in the query...

Comment: I learnt a lot from that reply. You can read about `group by` for "resampling" like this in many places but the fact Postgres won't "see through" the `date_trunc` and realize that it preserves the order of the underlying timestamps and hence can't make use of an index on them (would you agree with that assessment?) is rarely mentioned. Another thing that came to mind was to use `avg` as a window function over a `range`d window in a subquery from which we then filter out any values not at midnight (assuming there's always a value at midnight, i.e. fixed times).